# Функция текста наоборот

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь создать функцию для Дискорд бота, но не понимаю что не так:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rev(ctx, outp):
    res = outp[::-1]
    await ctx.channel.send(res)
```

Comment: а в чём ошибка? я проверил, всё работает

Comment: Я у себя бота запускаю в Дискорд захожу ввожу название функции и сам текст перевёрнутый, ничего не происходит.

Comment: А в чём ошибка?

Comment: Сам не понимаю, тоже проверил всё(отдельно) работает, наверное интернет плохой.